# Reading a file line by line and extract values

Tags: php

I need to do a routine that is able to extract values from a file and send these values to a mySQL database.

However my routine is returning some, imo, odd results.

This is my code:

```
$file = new SplFileObject($file_name);
for($i = 1 ; $i <= 5 ; $i++)
//while (!$file->eof())
{
    $linha = $file->fgets();
    echo $linha.'<br>';
    $line = explode(" ", $linha);
    print_r($line);
    echo '<br'>;
}
$file = null;
```

I used to have a while loop to run the whole file, but was getting an error and then decided to do a for loop to have a smaller number of results.

The results I get are:

```
1 1412114400 100 20 10 2 1 80 15 8 1.5 true 20 5 

Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1412114400 [2] => 100 [3] => 20 [4] => 10 [5] => 2 [6] => 1 [7] => 80 [8] => 15 [9] => 8 [10] => 1.5 [11] => true [12] => 20 [13] => 5 ) 

Array ( [0] => ) 

2 1412114460 100 20 10 2 1 80 15 8 1.5 true 20 5 

Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 1412114460 [2] => 100 [3] => 20 [4] => 10 [5] => 2 [6] => 1 [7] => 80 [8] => 15 [9] => 8 [10] => 1.5 [11] => true [12] => 20 [13] => 5 ) 

Array ( [0] => ) 

3 1412114520 100 20 10 2 1 80 15 8 1.5 true 20 5 

Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 1412114520 [2] => 100 [3] => 20 [4] => 10 [5] => 2 [6] => 1 [7] => 80 [8] => 15 [9] => 8 [10] => 1.5 [11] => true [12] => 20 [13] => 5 )
```

It seems that for every other cicle the `fgets()` function returns a "\n\r" and I don't know how to get rid of it.

EDIT:

I've used `trim()` and `str_replace()` and got the same result, so maybe I'm not getting a "\n\r".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$file = new SplFileObject($file_name);
$i = 1;
while ($i <= 5) {  
    $linha = trim($file->fgets());
    if ($linha == '') {
        continue;
    }
    echo $linha.'<br>';
    $line = explode(" ", $linha);
    print_r($line);
    echo '<br>';
    $i++;
}
$file = null;
```

Comment: I've tried `trim()` and `str_replace()` and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Comum Ah in that case you have empty lines in your file?

Comment: No, the file has every line with that same structure of values.

Comment: When you tried, was it exactly like I posted? Seems to work here. Maybe you could link us to the input file

Comment: Yes, I did exactly like that, one at a time and both ways at the same time. I'll upload the file here then.

Comment: The file does, indeed, have empty lines as I suspected. I'll update my answer.

Comment: It works! I've also rechecked my file generator, and there was an extra '\n' appended to the string. However when I opened the file using my texteditor, it did not show. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

to get rid of `\r\n` use:

```
$line = str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "\r\n"), array('', '', ''), $line);
```

I would also recommend using `file_get_contents()` as it offers a much cleaner way of reading files: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

You are also missing a `>` off your second `<br>`

Comment: Wouldn't `file_get_contents()` make a really large string? I want to read line by line because the file has 1440 lines. By using `file_get_contents()` won't the routine be very slow?

Also the `str_replace()` doesn't seem to work for my code.

Comment: Yes, I copied and pasted it after I exploded the string. Then I decided to do it after the line was read, and explode the string after the `str_replace()`. Both times I got the same result.

Comment: Yes, I've checked the second `<br>` and on my code I have it correctly.

Comment: You can use `file_get_contents` then explode on new lines `\n` as it is just an easier way to do it